# Should I call setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval every time the app restarts?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background-fetch

I developed an app that uses background fetch. I set the minimum interval between updates to minimum:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

I thought that this value is saved by the system, so I don't have to set it again when/if the app restarts.
However, I've just noticed that the last background fetch on one of my devices was two weeks ago. I know, that the interval between updates can vary, but I don't think that two weeks is normal. Especially considering the fact that it worked for several months, calling background update every 20-30 minutes.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to get the `MinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` to check my theory (does anyone know how to get it by the way?). I only checked `application.backgroundRefreshStatus`, and it is equal to `UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable`, but I think (I'm not sure) this only means that the user allows the app to use background updates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it turned out that **NO, we don't need to call `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` every time the app restarts**.

I had an experiment: I set it to `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` (turned the background fetch on), then shut the app down manually (via the task manager) and then restarted it, but didn't call to `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval`. The app continued to perform background fetches as it used to.

I hope, that this information will be helpful for someone, since it is not explicitly stated in the documentation (at least, I didn't see it). As for me, I have to find another possible reason why my app didn't work for two weeks.